# Regex to stop detect link when reach an &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I tried to find a regex to detect any link in a string.

Currenly using: `/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g`

This works fine until I see this kind of link:

```
http://campus.inkrement.no/Show/Index/2757798&nbsp;for&nbsp;å&nbsp;lære&nbsp;mer
```

I want it to end at the first `&nbsp;`

So it will be:

```
<a href='http://campus.inkrement.no/Show/Index/2757798'>http://campus.inkrement.no/Show/Index/2757798</a>&nbsp;for&nbsp;å&nbsp;lære&nbsp;mer
```

Instead of like this:

```
<a href='http://campus.inkrement.no/Show/Index/2757798&nbsp;for&nbsp;å&nbsp;lære&nbsp;mer'>http://campus.inkrement.no/Show/Index/2757798&nbsp;for&nbsp;å&nbsp;lære&nbsp;mer</a>
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: You could try running a second regexp after the first match to cut everything after and including the first &nbsp;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use negative lookahead here

something like:

```
/(https?:\/\/(?:(?!&nbsp;)[\S])+)/g
```

`[\S]` will match any non space

`(?!&nbsp;)` only if there's no `&nbsp;` ahead

`?:` will prevent from catching this group (optional)

Answer (score 1):

You could add just a few characters to your expression to get this:

`/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+?)(?=&nbsp;)|(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g`

**SAMPLE:**

`http://campus.inkrement.no/Show/Index/2757798&nbsp;for&nbsp;å&nbsp;lære&nbsp;mer`

**OUTPUT:**

`http://campus.inkrement.no/Show/Index/2757798`

Comment: @Adassko yeah you're right, I just checked that. So yours is the best choice for me right now. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Adassko you are right, edited it the easiest way... Now it works, anyway  thx. : ) Is there a way to use `?` with `lookahead` 's?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+?)&nbsp;/g` do the trick? Just notice that you match the first `&nbsp;` as well, so you'll need to add it to your replacement string. Is there always a closing `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help :( This will stop when it reach the last '&nbsp;', but I want it to stop at the first 'nbsp;'

Comment: Please note the `?` after the `+`, making it reluctant (it will match as little as possible). Did you try that?

Comment: @SQB still you would add `&nbsp` to the result, he didn't want it.

Comment: Yes, so I noted it needed to be added to the replacement string. In general, people seem to forget that if you're replacing, you can match as much of the surrounding string as you like, _as long as you replace it with itself_. Often, you don't need the (costly) lookaround.